# How to remove xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#" from Yoast Breadcrumbs?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, yoast

I want to remove  **xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#"** from Yoast Breadcrumbs code for accessibility reasons. Currently the only solution to this problem for me is to create custom breadcrumbs.

Here is my code.

```
 <span id="breadcrumbs">
    <span xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#">
        <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
            <a href="http://www.example.com/" rel="v:url" property="v:title">
                <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            </a> 
              /   
              <span rel="v:child" typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
                  <a href="http://www.example.com/" rel="v:url" property="v:title">Hello</a>
                   /   
                   <strong class="breadcrumb_last">World</strong>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="print-holder">
        <a href="javascript:window.print()" aria-label="Print">
            <i class="fa fa-print print-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
    </span>
</span>
```

How I call the code in PHP:

```
<?php
    if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
       yoast_breadcrumb('<span id="breadcrumbs">','<span class="print-holder"><a href="javascript:window.print()" aria-label="Print"><i class="fa fa-print print-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span></span>');
        }
?>
```

Comment: What is the problem with the namespace? What does it break?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand exactly what you mean by namespace in this case.  I've updated the HTML code. I found out that this "xmlns:v" attribute is written in the function and maybe I'd have to change it with filter. I don't know, i'm just guessing..